# Tensorflow for document type classification

Tags: android, tensorflow

I've tried several ways to create android app to classify (with Tensorflow) that image on camera view IS document of my type OR NOT. 
I've decided to create my custom model for this classification task.

First I try to use CustomVision helper, I've created 'model.pb' file, train it on 100 correct images of my document and 50 images on this document with mistakes (I know that its very small number of images, but that's all i have at the moment). On the output I have 'model.pb' and 'labels'(`'correct' and 'invalid'`) files. I put it in android example ([custom vision sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-android-customvision-sample)) and it work very sadly: app always says that all I'm seeing in the camera screen (peoples, desks, windows, nature...) - is my CORRECT document label. Only sometimes, if I catch document with wrong stamps in the camera screen I've got INVALID label.

So i've decided to use more complex model and simple re-train it. 
I've used this tutorial to get model and train it ([Tensorflow for Poets codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_machinelearning_063016&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc#0)). But the situation is the same: all in camera view detecting such as 'correct' and sometimes (when i put camera on document with wrong angle or not full document) - 'invalid'

SO MY QUESTION IS:

What I'm doing in concept way wrong? Maybe I train models in wrong way? Or maybe tensorflow models couldn't be used to goal os detection documents on screen?